# Drupal CTools access check

Tags: php, drupal, panels, drupal-ctools

I want to create a ctools access check for my panel selection rule.
What I wanna do, is to check a field value in a content type. The field is named field_layout with the options 3,2,1.

I created the access check and settings and the rule is showing up in the selection rule options. I can add it without any problems and set it up as I want to.

The only problem I have is, that the rule wont take effect ... :-/

Here is the code I use:

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugins are described by creating a $plugin array which will
 * be used by the system that includes the file.
 */
$plugin = array(
    'title' => t('Node: field layout'),
    'description' => t('Controls access by field_layout'),
    'callback' => 'he_layout_field_layout_ctools_access_check',
    'settings form' => 'he_layout_field_layout_ctools_settings',
);

/**
 * Custom callback defined by 'callback' in the $plugin array.
 *
 * Check for access.
 */
function he_layout_field_layout_ctools_access_check($conf, $context) {
    // If for some unknown reason that $context isn't set, we just want to be sure.
    if (empty($context) || empty($context->data) || empty($context->data->field_layout)) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    // If the layout set in the panels visibility rule settings is different from the field_layout
    // access to the pane is denied.
    $layout = $context->data->field_layout;
    if ($layout !== $conf['field_layout'][$context->data->field_layout[field_language('node', $context->data, 'field_layout')][0]['value']]) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

/**
 * Settings form for the 'field_layout' access plugin.
 */
function he_layout_field_layout_ctools_settings($form, &$form_state, $conf) {
    $form['settings']['field_layout'] = array(
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#title' => t('Layout'),
         '#options' => array(
            0 => '3',
            1 => '2',
            2 => '1',
        ),
        '#default_value' => $conf['field_layout'],
    );
    return $form;
}
```

The code is based on this tutorial: 
http://ramlev.dk/blog/2012/03/30/create-a-ctools-access-plugin/

Someone got an idea why this wont work?

Comment: It look like it've something to do with that: $layout = $context->data->field_layout;
Seems like it wont return a value?!

Answer (score 1):

@Basti's comment is correct, just one more step up:

```
$plugin = array(
    'title' => t('Node: field layout'),
    'description' => t('Controls access by field_layout'),
    'callback' => 'he_layout_field_layout_ctools_access_check',
    'settings form' => 'he_layout_field_layout_ctools_settings',
    // 'required context' => new ctools_context_required(t('Node'), 'node'),
);
```

It is ok if don't need the context for your plugin. But the `$context` argument in the access check receives exactly the context you mentioned, which means you always get null when you specify no `required context`.

This way, you alway have `false` at the first check from this: `if (empty($context)`